# MediaPlayer Using DropBox URL to play video

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, mpmovieplayercontroller, dropbox

Hi im creating an app for a uni project which requires me to play videos from a server.
i've decided to use Dropbox. However it would not play the file, is there any way for me to do it? or do i need to get the video from somewhere else.

ive tried another link which works perfectly fine. (not dropbox however)

http://www.jplayer.org/video/m4v/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer.m4v

my Coding Below

AnimeWatchViewController.m

```
//
//  AnimeWatchViewController.m
//  VideoPlayer
//
//  Created by Alex Lee on 27/04/2014.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Alex Lee. All rights reserved.
//

#import "AnimeWatchViewController.h"

@interface AnimeWatchViewController ()

@end

@implementation AnimeWatchViewController

@synthesize moviePlayer;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


}

-(IBAction)playMovie{

    NSURL * url =[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"https://www.dropbox.com/s/t05zdw2woogo4kh/ACW_3.mp4"];

    moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

    [moviePlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 100, 275, 150)];
    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];

    moviePlayer.fullscreen = YES;
    moviePlayer.allowsAirPlay = YES;
    moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
    moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlModeDefault;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

AnimeWatchViewController.h

```
//
//  AnimeWatchViewController.h
//  VideoPlayer
//
//  Created by Alex Lee on 27/04/2014.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Alex Lee. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

@interface AnimeWatchViewController : UIViewController

@property(nonatomic,strong) MPMoviePlayerController * moviePlayer;


-(IBAction)playMovie;
@end
```

Comment: There are several options that could be the root of your problem. 1. HTTP-communication (maybe wrong MIME-type, maybe some weird other quirks introduced by DropBox) - check that by using a proxy like Charles and compare both scenarios. 2. Encoding incompatibilities - check the exact codec and file encoding of your offending video and compare the results with the compatibility list from Apple. 3. Size restrictions - you are not using proper HTTP-streaming, hence file size does matter - try it with a short clip. Lastly, when in doubt if your code is the cause, use the browser to test playback.

Answer (score 7):

You're using the URL https://www.dropbox.com/s/t05zdw2woogo4kh/ACW_3.mp4, but that's not a link to a video... it's a link to a page with a video on it.

To convert it to a direct link to the video, change `www.dropbox.com` to `dl.dropboxuser.com`, like this: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/t05zdw2woogo4kh/ACW_3.mp4

Comment: Thank you soooo much!Is there a way to bring the control up. like pause etc. doesnt seem to happen on my simulation

Answer (score 0):

for that you have to first get direct download link then you can play video directly from dropbox server

[Try to understand this link may help you](http://tricksbuzz.com/get-direct-link-dropbox/)